# SSL Certificate Domain Name Mismatch

Tags: tomcat, ssl-certificate, openssl

Retina is complaining that the SSL certificate running on my Tomcat server does not return the fully qualified domain name (fqdn) but rather the IP. I connected to my Tomcat server on port 443 using the command: `openssl s_client -connect <ip>:443` and it shows me the **CN=mymachine.mydomain.net**. Nowhere do I see the IP address being displayed. However, Retina says the **Found Value** is an IP address.

I followed the directions [here at Bill Comer's Blog](http://billcomer.blogspot.com/2010/03/ssl-tomcat-and-self-signed-certificates.html) to create a self-signed certificate. I don't see how the **Found Value** can be the IP address of the Target Host Name rather than the fqdn.

What command is Retina sending to determine this? What else am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you keep your CSRs?

Comment: @Simon: Yes, I have them

Comment: I did `openssl req -in <csr_file> -noout -text` and it shows the CN=<myhostname>

Comment: @0A0D Does the certificate have subject alternative names?

Comment: @ShaneMadden: Nope.

Comment: [Delayed response]  I'm stumped.  I'm not familiar with Retina - could it be performing a forward and then reverse-DNS lookup, and failing to resolve the reverse?  Straws... clutching.

Comment: @SimonCatlin: It was due to the DNS server returning the wrong hostname!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System Administrator had to add machines to DNS server and problem went away. This problem did not get noticed even by doing a nslookup from the Retina machine.